# Let $\mu$ and $ \nu$ be measures on $(\mathscr \Omega , \mathscr F )$

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, examples-counterexamples, self-learning

I have two questions `Question 1` and `Question 2` see below.

This is an extension of(Problem 32.9 from the Billiglsey Probability and measure.)

$$$$

Let $\mu$ and $ \nu$  be measures on $(\mathscr \Omega , \mathscr F )$
and suppose that $\mathscr F^o$  is a σ-field contained in $\mathscr F$.

Then the restrictions $\mu^ο$ and $ \nu^ο$ of $\mu$ and $\nu$ to  $\mathscr F^o$ are measures on $(\mathscr \Omega , \mathscr F^o )$.

Assume that $ \nu^ο$ is σ-finite (which implies that $ \nu$ is also σ-finite).
Let $ \nu_{ac}$, $ \nu_{s}$, $ \nu_{ac}^o$, and  $ \nu_{s}^o$
be, respectively, the absolutely continuous and singular parts of  $ \nu$ and $ \nu^ο$ with respect to $\mu$ and $\mu^ο$.

**Part A :**  Show   $ \nu_{ac}^o (E) \ge \nu_{ac} (E)  $  and  $ \nu_{s}^o (E)   \le \nu_{s} (E) $ for $E   \in  \mathscr F^o$.

I think I managed to solve Part A , since for every $E   \in  \mathscr F^o$
Case 1 : IF  $\nu_{s} (E)=0$ , then  $\nu_{s} (E) \ge \nu_{s}^o (E)    $
Case 2 : IF $\nu_{s} (E)>0$ , then  $\mu^o (E) =\mu^o (E)=0 $ , then $ \nu_{ac}^o (E) = \nu_{ac} (E) =0  $ and $\nu_{s} (E) = \nu (E) - \nu_{ac} (E) =  \nu (E) =  \nu^o (E) = \nu^o (E) = \nu^o (E) - \nu_{ac}^o (E) = \nu_{s}^o (E) $.

So ,  $ \nu_{s} (E)  \ge \nu_{s}^o (E)$

`Question 1` **Does this mean**   $ \nu_{ac}^o (E) \ge \nu_{ac} (E)  $  and  $ \nu_{s}^o (E)   \le \nu_{s} (E) $ for $E   \in  \mathscr F^o$ **???**

My `Question 2` is in **Part B** below:

**Part B :**  I need to give an example to show that strict inequality may hold.

As a   **hint** I should let $\mu$ and $ \nu$  be probability measures  measures on a two-point space and then take $\mathscr F^o = {(\emptyset , \Omega  )} $

(Problem 32.9 from the Billiglsey Probability and measure.)  a short solution for this part  which is not complete is the below

For the case where $\mathscr F^o = { (\emptyset , \Omega)  } $ , in which $ \nu^o$  is absolutely continouse with respect to $ \mu^o$ ( provided that $ \mu (\Omega) \ge 0 )$ and hence $\nu_{s}^o$ vanishes.

I do not understand this solution, and why it vanishes.